# How can I hide Swagger at production profile?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, profile

I tried to add a `profile annotation` on `SwaggerConfig` class. 
I used !local for test to see if it works, then I will change it to: !prod

```
@profile("!local")
```

---

this img before annotation
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye13Y.png)

this img after annotation
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYKGq.png)

I think something is triggering `Swagger`. Help me :( 
my config class

```java
@Profile("!local")
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig{

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("private packageName"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build());
    }
```

my application yml file

```yaml
spring:
    profiles:
      active: local
```

Comment: You should show us your configuration file and how you launch/compile your app in order to see that your `Spring` is indeed taking your profile into account.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should help you in hiding swagger ui in prod.

```
 @Profile({"!prod && !local"})
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfig{
    
        @Bean
        public Docket swaggerConfiguration() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("private packageName"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                    .build());
        }
```